# Convert PCAP to MAC addresses in Python

Tags: scapy, pcap

I'm tryng to read a Pcap file, and after that I get the Ip's and the realtions between Ip's, I want to transform these relattions in MAC relations but I'm not sure how I have to do it.

```
trafico= rdpcap('example-01.pcap')

unique_streams =[]
for frame in trafico:
    packet = frame[IP]
    src = packet.src
    dst = packet.dst
    layer4_segment = packet.payload.name
    sport = packet[layer4_segment].sport
    dport = packet[layer4_segment].dport
    unique_streams.append(f"{src}:{dst}:{layer4_segment}:{sport}:{dport}")
    tre= set(unique_streams)
    for k in tre:
        print(k)
```

I have these code to show the Ip's source and destination and also the ports

thanks

Comment: It is unclear for me what you are asking. Title asks for MAC while body of the questions asks for *"Ip's or the realtions between Ip's"* - which are in total three different things.

Comment: Sorry to not be very clear with the explanation, I have the relations between Ip's and also the source and destionation ports, but I don't know how to transform these relations in MAC relations...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't know how to transform these relations in MAC relations...

To get the MAC from the packet you need to look at the 'Ether' layer and not the'IP' layer:

```
e = frame[Ether]
print(e.src,e.dst)
```

`e.src` is the MAC for the IP `packet.src` etc.

Comment: I added your code to my lines and It works. I putted in the same way, in the "for" statment but without the "print" command.  e = frame[Ether]
(e.src,e.dst). And after : unique_streams.append(f"{src}:{dst}:{layer4_segment}:{sport}:{dport}:{e.src}:{e.dst}"). Thanks